# Php, Mysql sort results based on number of records from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm joining two tables to display car brands. Here is the structure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  b.title
FROM
  brands as b 
  INNER JOIN items as i 
    ON i.brand_id = b.id 
WHERE i.status = 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(i.brand_id) DESC;
```

The above only produces one record. If I remove `"ORDER BY COUNT(i.brand_id) DESC;"` it displays all the records correctly.

I would like to sort result based on number of vehicles under each brand category. So for example if bmw category has the most car listed under, it should be the first one.

Comment: you have no `group by`, so mysql is collapsing all the records into a single one.

Comment: @marc B why do I need to group by when using DISTINCT?

Comment: You say you want to sort based on count of vehicles, but no where do you define what constitutes a vehicle.  A brand has many Vehicles each with a unique VIN (I hope). You're displaying the brand title but not the count... I guess I need to see expected results to figure out what it is you need...  DISTINCT eliminates duplicate records USUALLY used by novice users because a join isn't setup correctly or tables are structured poorly resulting in duplicate data.  any time you use an aggregate, you SHOULD use a group by to tell the engine how you want the data aggregated.

Comment: @xQbert I have removed DISTINCT and added GROUP BY b.id and works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT b.title
FROM brands as b 
  INNER JOIN items as i 
    ON i.brand_id = b.id 
WHERE i.status = 1
GROUP BY b.title
ORDER BY COUNT(i.brand_id) DESC;`

This should work for you.

I would use

`SELECT b.title, count(i.brand_id)
FROM items i
  LEFT JOIN brands as b
    ON b.id = i.brand_id 
WHERE i.status = 1
GROUP BY i.brand_id
ORDER BY COUNT(i.brand_id) DESC;`

Your concern is the amount of cars in inventory. You want to break them down by how many of each brand you have. So, you're mainly concerned with the items tables and only need the brands table to get the information stored in the items table (brand name). Lastly, in order to get aggregate the number of brands of each, you must let MySQL know what you want in the `GROUP BY`.

I haven't used an EXPLAIN, but I would think the bottom query is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could join `brands` on an aggregate query:

```
SELECT     b.title
FROM       brands b 
INNER JOIN (SELECT   brand_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM     items
            WHERE    status = 1
            GROUP BY brand_id) i ON i.brand_id = b.id 
ORDER BY   cnt DESC;
```